# Tkinter "out of stack space" error with Pymol on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, tkinter, pymol

I've been writing a plugin for Pymol (visualization software for macromolecular structures). For this I am using python and tkinter.

My plugin works, and I can register it in the Pymol "Plugin" Menu.

After installing the plugin.py file from the Pymol-own Plugin Manager, there are three options to start the plugin:

1) Plugin Menu --> "Plugin Name"   |   Works on Linux and Windows

2) Pymol Command Line --> Testplugin   |   Works only on Linux

3) from the Pymol main window CTRL+F   |   Works only on Linux

The error I get in cases 2 and 3 on windows machines is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyMOL_1760\PyMOL/modules\pymol\parser.py", line 256, in parse
    self.result=apply(layer.kw[0],layer.args,layer.kw_args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyMOL_1760\PyMOL/modules\pmg_tk\startup\tkintertest.py", line 43, in showWindow
    top = Toplevel(parent)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyMOL_1760\PyMOL\py27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2017, in __init__
    BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyMOL_1760\PyMOL\py27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1974, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

I have provided a minimal "working" plugin code below. All this does is just open a new window and display a label "Testlabel". Again, you can start the plugin from Pymol on Linux with all three methods, whereas on Windows only the first method works and the other two give the out of stack error above. This has been tested with different Windows/Linux/Pymol versions.

Minimal code example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
from pymol import cmd, plugins


class Testplugin(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()      
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.labelTest = Label(self,
            text = "Testlabel"
        )

        self.labelTest.grid(
            in_ = self,
            column = 1,
            row = 1,
            columnspan = 1,
            ipadx = 0,
            ipady = 0,
            padx = 0,
            pady = 0,
            rowspan = 1,
            sticky = "n"
        )

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize = 30, pad = 3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize = 30, pad = 3)


def __init__(self):
    self.menuBar.addmenuitem("Plugin", "command", label="Testplugin", command = showWindow)

def showWindow():
    parent = plugins.get_tk_root()
    top = Toplevel(parent)
    frame = Testplugin(top)

cmd.extend("Testplugin", showWindow)
cmd.set_key("CTRL-F", showWindow)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how to suppressed `init` function ? you got more than one Toplevel call.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get what you mean here. Where are the two Toplevel calls you refer to? Thx anyway!

Comment: `class Testplugin(Frame):` you not asking question before typing this. Did you count "how much __init__ you got  ?  "Don't use  copy paste codes, learn how to work ! @fumarat need learn `call` and `__init__` differences first.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort in helping me with this issue! However, I cannot quite get what you are trying to tell me in your comments. First of all, let me clarify, that the code I attached to my question is supposed to work **only** in the PyMol environment; hence the two `__init__`. The first `__init__` is within the Testplugin class. The second `__init__` is necessary for initializing the plugin itself in the PyMol context. Please have a look at https://github.com/speleo3/pymol/blob/master/modules/pmg_tk/startup/remote_pdb_load.py. This is the standard procedure for PyMol plugins.